# How do I test a Material UI Button's background color with Testing Library?

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library

Material UI's [Button](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) component renders a relatively straightforward button element with a background color which we can see in a web inspector.

But when we examine this with getComputedStyle in a testing-library/react render, the reported color is 'transparent'.

Is there a way to test the button's background color?

For example, if a component returns:

```
<Button data-testid="blah" variant="contained" color="primary">
  hi
</Button>
```

It creates a blue button (#3f51b5) with the default theme. But this test:

```
it("renders with the correct background color", () => {
  const { getAllByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const button = getAllByTestId("blah")[0];
  const buttonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(button);
  const backgroundColor = buttonStyle["background-color"];
  expect(backgroundColor).toEqual("#3f51b5");
});
```

Fails with

```
Expected: "#3f51b5"
Received: "transparent"
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-color-test-y271j?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Got an [answer to this on GitHub](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24761#issuecomment-772810211), but long story short, this is a consequence of how JSDOM works. The "solution" is to test this with something like Cypress, not Testing Library. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯